# IA64 doesn't correspond to IEEE standard for float numbers?

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee

I tried this code to represent float number storing  system:

```
float *f = new float();
int *i = new int();
i = reinterpret_cast<int *>(f);
std::bitset<32> *bs;

std::cin>>*f;
bs = new std::bitset<32>(*i);
std::cout<<*bs<<" == "<<*f<<std::endl;
```

But when it run with 23.5 the result is `01000001-10111100-00000000-00000000`. The power is `10000001=63`.
Shouldn't it be 64 due to IEEE standard?
And the mantis should be `00010111-10000000-00000000`. Is that true?

**Note**: I compiled this code with GCC and VS both. The result was same.

Comment: What number did you input?

Comment: the exponent is the 8 bits after the sign bit. sign: 0 exponent: 10000011=131 But the input would be nice to answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`01000001-10111100-00000000-00000000`

`0 10000011 01111000000000000000000`

```
sign: 0
exponent: 10000011_binary = 131_decimal
mantissa: 01111000000000000000000_binary
mantissa is defined by 1.<mantissa>
so -> 1.01111_binary

exponent is defined this way: exp-127
-> 131-127 = 4
-> 1.01111_binary * 2^4
-> comma shift to the right by 4 
--> 10111.1_binary = 23.5_decimal
```

generally:

```
(-1)^sign * 1.<mantissa> * 2^(exponent-127)
```

Comment: That what an exponent of the base does, it shifts the decimal point. Like 3 x 10^5 = 3.000000 x 10^5 = 300000.0000

Comment: Thank you @mister yeti. Is it IEEE standard?

Comment: This is IEEE 754 for 32bit floats